# How to analyse Bitcoin Blockchain data from Bitcoin Core?

Tags: python, block, blockchain, bitcoin, explorer

I'm running a Bitcoin Full Node and I'm wondering how to import the data that is saved on my computer to Python in order to do some analyses. Would be glad about recommendations for packages that help with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't describe an issue. Loading and analyzing data could mean anything. Without knowing what you want to do the only advice one can give is to google for `python data analysis`. If you know the name fo the analysis you want to perform, google for `python that-name`

Comment: Use the bitcoin RPC, there are many python packages that are built to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bitcoin JSON RPC API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)), and use commands from the [list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list):

- getblockcount - returns cullent chain height
- getblockhash **block_no** - returns block hash on specific height (do loop for iterate blocks)
- getblock **blockhash** - get block info, including list of TXIDs (ID of
  transactions)
- getrawtransaction **TXID** **1** - returns decoded specific
  transaction by ID1